# NullPointerException even if I did put a value in the variable?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have this code and it takes the location where the user pressed on the Google Map and it takes the longitude and latitude and I put the value in two variables. But it still gives me a `NullPointerException`. Why ?

And I did try the code before and it did work.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView mv) {
    int i = e.getAction();

    MainActivity test = new MainActivity();

    switch(i) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // When your finger stop touching the screen
            Log.d("ACTION UP", "Finger was removed from screen");

            lng = (int) e.getX();
            lat = (int) e.getY();
            test.placePinFromTouch(lat, lng); // This is the NullPointerException line
            break;
    }
```

Where I commented in the code above is where I get the `NullPointerException`, but I wonder why in this touchEvent I'm getting this.

Comment: Are you sure `test` isn't null?

Comment: Your `test` object is most likely not initialized

Comment: Well i have this where i define all my variables: MainActivity test;  Do i have to do like MainActivity test = new MainActivity() ?

Comment: @TheCompBoy: yes, you _have to_ initialize it. I have no idea if that is the right way to do it though.

Comment: -1 Lack of debugging. Using a debugger (or "println") it will be trivial to see what is in `test`. Including a stack-trace will enable *us* (and you!) to see if it came from `test` being null or originated from within the `placePinFromTouch` method.

Comment: @pst, By default android apps can't do much with `println`, as stdout and stderr is sent to `/dev/null`.  However, he still could use Log, and toast (and a proper debugger), for debugging.

Comment: Actually stdout and stderr are printed in the Logcat with the tags `System.out` and `System.err`.

Comment: That's not what the documentation says: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html read "Viewing stdout and stderr".   I can image though that OEMs have changed this

Comment: Mhm interesting. Guess the doc isn't up to date (that part didn't change since february 2009), just tested it on a HTC Desire with sense, one with cyanogenmod 7.0 and a 2.2. emulator. All behave the same. Anyway, doesn't matter. He could have used some way of printing easily.

Comment: Fair enough.  I haven't even tried to do it since 2.0 anyway, but if the emulator does it, than I bet its official.  I wonder what is involved in getting that page changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `test` object certainly isn't null.  However, we need to know what types lng and lat are.    Sure, you are casting what you pass into them as an int, but java has a habit of autoboxing data.  It could be the case that they are null.  If they are of type int, then they are not null.  However, if they are of type Integer, they might be.

Finally we need to know if `placePinFromTouch` will explicitly throw a null pointer exception, especially on unusual values of `lat` and `lng`.  Yes, that is not the appropriate thing to do there, but I've seen worse things done with exceptions.